# Android ListView Issue With Layout Set to Gone

Tags: android, listview, height

Hi I have a listView and just below it a layout with numbers(it's a custom "keyboard")hidden and below this layout another layout which is always visible. My problem is that if I use relativeLayout and try to put keyboard visibility to GONE and then to VISIBLE the keyboard will not become visible. It's like the listView doesn't know that a new layout is visible and it doesn't resize. Below is the code. Any answer would be highly appreciated.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:background="@color/white_to_gray"
        >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/keyboard_menu"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <com.example.Keyboard android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="50dp"
                          android:id="@+id/keyboard_layout"
                          android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                          android:visibility="gone"/>

    <include layout="@layout/menu"
             android:id="@+id/menu"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try giving weight to each view

Comment: Could you show the code relevant to when you make the VISIBLE call please?

Comment: I only make a Keyboard object and set it's visibility to Visible so I don't think the problem is there.